# DNS leaking on Ubuntu 16

Tags: networking, network-manager, security, dns, vpn

I use a VPN. When I check DNS leak testing sites, my original ISP is shown. My government in the UK logs and spies on every internet connection legally and I don't want this to happen because although I am not doing anything wrong, I fear this will be misused and I want to be private.

I have researched and got nowhere with the solutions suggested. My DNS still leaks. What to do? My Windows laptop doesn't leak my DNS, this is a problem with Ubuntu. Does anyone have a definite solution that works and even when you restart your computer? I am not a techie either, so bear that in mind.

Comment: To add, my ISP's router does not allow changing the DNS server. I even tried editing the file but the router overrides it (Sky Hub).  They do not allow using a different router either.

Comment: Change the DNS server used by your computer.  Take it off DHCP for all things, have the VPN configuration override the DNS to use (in Network Manager typically you can set this, and rely on the connection for DHCP addresses only and then hand pick your search domain and DNS servers to use for each connection)

Comment: Some ISP's are now using a technology called 'Transparent DNS proxy'. Using this technology, they will intercept all DNS lookup requests (TCP/UDP port 53) and transparently proxy the results. This effectively forces you to use their DNS service for all DNS lookups.

Comment: @heynnema: DNSSEC can't become the norm soon enough…

Comment: @DavidFoerster not guaranteed to be a protection against transparent proxies though

Comment: @ThomasWard: No, but it will make them more apparent and it's more difficult to inject bogus DNS responses, e. g. for non-existing domain names.

Answer (score 0):

This solution applies only to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, where DNS leaks have appeared.    Editing each and every .ovpn file with a script as advised by others, may work, it may not.  For me it did not.  If you have been doing this, replace the ovpn files with fresh ones and proceed.

If you have been mucking around for quite some time with this problem, a fresh install could be indicated, to which you can immediately implement this simple solution successfully.

This solution, may work for other Distro derivations to 16.04 LTS, that‘s possible, I have not tested this.  This solution presumes you‘ve been successful in importing VPN config files and applied them only to discover a DNS leak of your IP's DNS server has shown up in a DNS Leak test.

**What this solution does is force your computer to use only the DNS server as provided by your VPN provider's ovpn file.**

In the terminal:

```
sudo su

<enter your password>

apt-get install openresolv nscd unbound
```

Allow the install to proceed past the reboot recommendation. When finished, close the terminal.

For good measure, reboot your computer, start up your VPN and check with a DNS leak test.  You should see only your VPN‘s DNS server listed.  If you see your IP‘s DNS server, check your other VPN config files to see if this isn‘t just an aberation with your VPN provider‘s server.